# Chakra UI: Responsive Toast Notifications

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm using chakra UI for my application and this is the code block I'm calling to display the notification.

```
const successToast = useToast({
    title: 'Logged In',
    description: "Waiting for developers to build redirect pages",
    status: 'success',
    duration: 5000,
    isClosable: true,
    position: "bottom-right",
  })
```

Chakra offers a way to handle responsive designs: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/responsive-styles. So I want the notification to be shown on top when using a mobile device. For which I tried doing:

```
position: {base: 'top-right', lg:'bottom-right'}
```

But I get error saying:

```
(property) UseToastOptions.position?: ToastPositionWithLogical | undefined
The placement of the toast

@default

"bottom"
Type '{ base: string; lg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ToastPositionWithLogical | undefined'.
  Type '{ base: string; lg: string; }' is not assignable to type '"bottom-right"'.
```

Previously when I used this method to make other design elements it worked. How do I fix it or make it responsive for this.

Toast Notification Docs: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `useBreakpointValue` hook.

```js
const position = useBreakpointValue({ base: 'top-right', mlg: 'bottom-right' }) as any;

function displayToast(){
    const successToast = useToast({
    // [...]
    position: position,
  })
}
```

Edit: Added `as any` as position accepts only `ToastPositionWithLogical`

Comment: Thanks I tried this, but it says: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ToastPositionWithLogical | undefined'.     
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ToastPositionWithLogical | undefined'.

Comment: Just checked chakra toast docs, position accepts a type called ToastPositionWithLogical, and we are passing in a string. But I couldn't figure how to pass it as ToastPositionWithLogical

Comment: Edit: I just added `is any` and it works, thank you

Comment: Done, was waiting for my edit to be accepted and thanks again :)